# jsTree node titles not displaying newlines

Tags: jstree

If a node contains newlines, jsTree prints them as whitespaces. For instance, this block of text:

> suggestion: Passwords of at least 10 characters are strongly recommended, especially considering that construction rules requiring both numbers and letters cannot be enforced by default.
>
> The following may need to be customized for your environment.  Add:
>
> min=10
>
> to the following line in /etc/pam.d/common-password by hand:
>
> password ... pam_unix.so ... min=10 ...
>
> IMPORTANT: the password length is only checked at the time of account creation or password update.  Existing users' password length should be double-checked to ensure that password minimum length is enforced.

is displayed like this:

> suggestion: Passwords of at least 10 characters are strongly recommended, especially considering that construction rules requiring both numbers and letters cannot be enforced by default. The following may need to be customized for your environment. Add: min=10 to the following line in /etc/pam.d/common-password by hand: password ... pam_unix.so ... min=10 ... IMPORTANT: the password length is only checked at the time of account creation or password update. Existing users' password length should be double-checked to ensure that password minimum length is enforced.

Is there a way to get jsTree to render newlines correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I got around it by substituting all newline characters ('\n') with `<br>` tags in the HTML. i.e., `gsub(/\n/,"<br>")`.